# sync develop branch from release commits in git

Tags: git

We have implemented [git model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) in our project. 
Developers have access to only develop branch. Release and master branch are in control of build engineer. During release planning stage we copy code from develop branch to release, and increment the version on develop branch.

Developer should create a bug fix branch from release and raise a pull request to merge it into release. So code goes to release branch directly bypassing develop branch.

I can click sync in Bit Bucket to get develop branch up to date, but it would be great to keep the branches in sync automatically.

Is there any way to automatically sync develop branch with the commits from release ? develop branch is now behind release  because it doesn't have the merge commits that happened from the pull request merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BitBucket webhooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html) to trigger every push to "release" branch, and then send this notification to Continuous Integration tool (Jenkins for example) to sync "release" with "develop".